# Broadcom wireless card in with Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, wifi, internet, broadcom

I just installed Fedora as a dual-boot (other OS in Win7) on my Dell Inspiron 1750 and, of course, the wireless card is missing firmware.

The wireless card is called Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN mini-card. When I run `lspci` on Fedora it says that the card is a BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01). Some internet searching shows that this card has had a lot of problems before.

I don't have access to wired internet, but I do have a USB flash drive. I'm using the instructions for Linux drivers from [Broadcom's own website](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php). To quote,

> Some of the major linux distros already supply a version of this
>   driver, so you don't have to compile your own.  Most of the distros
>   keep this driver along with other proprietary or non-GPL drivers in a
>   separate repository.
>
> For further information see the documentation for your specific
>   distro.
>
> Fedora:
>   ------ su -c 'rpm -Uvh
>
> http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
>   http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-stable.noarch.rpm
>
> su - yum update yum install kmod-wl

So I download the two `.rpm` files on Windows and copy them to Fedora, then use `rpm -ivh ...` on them. No idea what that does, but internet still doesn't work. Obviously I can't use `yum` because I don't have internet.

Is there a way where I can just download whatever I need, put the stuff on USB, and just install it with `rpm` or whatever? Because the fact that every tutorial out there assumes that the user has access to wired internet is killing me.

Comment: Fedora 16 is dead as a doornail. There isn't any really clean upgrade path anymore, better reinstall from scratch. And I believe latest Fedora supports the card out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

You need the file called `broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2`, which a quick internet search shows several places to download.

Put that on a USB stick, go to Fedora, navigate to right directory, and run

```
tar xvjf broadcom-wl-r.150.10.5.tar.bz2 && cd broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5
su
broadcom-wl-r.150.10.5/driver su b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware wl_apsta_mimo.o
```

Then restart Fedora. Boom! Internet.

Comment: The right directory is usually `/lib/firmware/`